# Export a java library in a .jar file

Tags: java, jar, export

I'm still pretty new to java and I'm VERY new to exporting .jar files. I've got a little game that I want to send to some friends and I was told in another question that I should export it to an executable jar file. Well I finally got that working on my computer but when I send it to other people it doesn't work because they don't have the library.

I'm importing the objectdraw library and without that my program won't run at all!

So basically I need to find a way to export the object draw library as part of my .jar file so that they can use it too. Do I simply include it in the included files part of the jar command?
ex: jar cmf MANIFEST.mf Archery.jar * /System/Library/Java/Extensions/objectdraw.jar

or what? I'm working out of the command line right now.

Comment: Are you working with the Eclipse IDE? The easiest way would be to use the export wizard...

Comment: No I've been working in the command line. I have netbeans but I have never used it.

Comment: Start using Eclipse. Or intelliJ. Or even NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the best way I've found to do this is to unpack the library and then put all the resulting files in with your final archive. This way it actually works on other computers.

```
jar xf library_wanted.jar; jar cvmf MANIFEST.mf end_result.jar *.class library_wanted/
```

Comment: What part of this solution didn't work? It's been 5 years since I did this. From what I remember I was just unpacking the .jar file and adding it into the final .jar file and I had no issues with it.

Comment: I've submitted an edit for your command to fix it. The order of end_result.jar was incorrect

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to send the JAR library file too and add a `Class-Path` entry to the manifest. This entry would look like:

```
Class-Path: objectdraw.jar
```

You could also set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable manually.

Alternatively, you can unpack the library and add all (or just the required files) to your final jar. This doesn't always work though, because some libraries rely on the integrity of teir JAR file.

Finally, it is possible to include the dependency in the main JAR, but it would require a custom class loader.

Comment: would the class path just be objectdraw.jar or the whole path?

Comment: @Cald If they're in the same directory, it would be just `objectdraw.jar`. You could also put the libraries in a subdirectory named `lib` and use `lib/objectdraw.jar` instead, for instance.

Comment: Okay I think I can do that then. Thanks for the help

Comment: I lied.... that did not work. It works on my computer just fine but when I try to run it on other people's computer it fails to open them. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong I've done it this way and I did a clean build on netbeans and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Cald Possibly transitive dependencies? See what class is reported not to be found in the remote computer.